# What is the identity element of 4

Tags: binary-operations, magma, cayley-table

If $*$ is a binary operation taking the greater of two distinct numbers, construct a table for the operation on the set $S=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. What is the identity element of 4? Is the operation commutative?

Comment: What do you mean by "the identity element of $4$"?

Comment: You seem to use words randomly...this has nothing to do with "integration", and I am not sure you know what an "identity element" means.  Please edit your post to ask a clear question.  And show your efforts!  Commutativity is easy to settle.  is $2$ the "identity element of $4$"?  Why or why not?

Comment: It might help the people answering the question if you include the definition of identity element.

Comment: As in the comment by @lulu , do you mean **the inverse element of 4** or **the identity element**?? :)

Comment: @Sefiuoyedeji Show please your attempts. What did you mean: "an identity element"?

Comment: @Sefiuoyedeji check if my answer helps! Also, edit your title and question accordingly to comments ;)

Answer (score 2):

Let $S=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and let $*$ be a binary operation:
$$
a*b:=\max(a,b).
$$

The operation $*$ is a **binary operation** on $S$ trivially, since $\max(a,b)$ is either $a$ or $b$ so $\max(a,b)\in S$ for all $a,b\in S$.

It is **commutative** since
$$
\max(b,a)=\max(a,b)
$$
for all $a,b\in S$.

Its Cayley table:
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
* & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
\hline
1 & \color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{2} & \color{blue}{3} & \color{blue}{4} & \color{blue}{5}\\
2 & \color{blue}{2} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
3 & \color{blue}{3} & 3 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
4 & \color{blue}{4} & 4 & 4 & 4 & 5\\
5 & \color{blue}{5} & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5\\
\end{array}
is indeed symmetric.

The **identity element** (unique) exists, it is $1$, left and right identity as highlighted in blue in the table.

Finally, $4$ has no left or right inverse, so **it has no inverse**: the identity $1$ does not appear in the line or column of the table labeled by $4$ and this is consistent with the fact that it does not exists any $x\in A$ such that
$$
\max(4,x)=1=\max(x,4).
$$

This $(S,*)$ seems to me to be a commutative [monoid](http://math.chapman.edu/~jipsen/structures/doku.php/monoids) but not a group (as we said, no inverse for $4$): being finite, of order $5$, cancellation holds if and only if division holds and indeed none of the two holds here. We see also this properties on the table since some elements are missing in some lines (columns) and, consequently, some are repeated.

Uh, I said *monoid* but I actually didn't mention associativity...can you prove that the operation is **associative** too?